# How to reference a file in another directory with the \input command under Windows 10

Tags: miktex, windows, paths

In a LaTeX document,  I am trying to place my pre-`\begin{document}` commands into a separate file.  I cannot find a Window 10 directory to store the file,  other than the current working directory.  The `\input` command does not accept `C:\dir\dir\filename.tex`.  Where can I store my command file or how does one reference a file in another directory?  Or is there a way to add a directory to the path list that MiKTeX searches?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: just use `dir/filename` with `/` even on windows.

Comment: Put the file in a local texmf. The miktex docu contains a entry about it.